Why TensorRT only supports 768x768 resolution image for stable-diffusion model?
I'm trying to accelerate stable-diffusion model with TensorRT. However according to this blog, we know that it only supports batch_size = [1, 4] and resolution = 768x768 for static model. I have following questions:

I know there is a 2GB tensor size limitation in TensorRT, but I'm wandering which tensor will cause this issue.
I converted a 1x3x2048x2048 static shape stable-diffusion model to onnx, it will occur a memory allocation error, why the down_blocks will cost 40GB memory?

[ONNXRuntimeError] : 6 : RUNTIME_EXCEPTION : Non-zero status code returned while running MatMul node. Name:'/unet/down_blocks.0/attentions.0/transformer_blocks.0/attn1/MatMul' Status Message: /onnxruntime_src/onnxruntime/core/framework/bfc_arena.cc:376 void* onnxruntime::BFCArena::AllocateRawInternal(size_t, bool, onnxruntime::Stream*, bool, onnxruntime::WaitNotificationFn) Failed to allocate memory for requested buffer of size 42949672960


While I can't run the static shape onnx model, I can run the dynamic shape onnx model and convert it to a static shape TRT engine(minShapes=optShapes=maxShape=1x3x2048x2048) to run a higher resolution.

I converted a static and dynamic shape onnx model, the static one will occur this issue due to it require a big cache while the dynamic shape onnx can convert to TRT engine successfully with the shape parameter: minShapes=1x3x2048x2048 optShapes=1x3x2048x2048 maxShape=1x3x2048x2048
